# How do I set text to 'Normal Text' while keeping style in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

So in order for my table of content working properly, I want to set some of my texts to `Normal Text` (which removes them from the table of content) while keeping its styles. Is it possible to achieve this? Or I need to set it to `Normal Text` then re-apply the styles back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set it to `normal text` and re-paint the formatting, yes. The format painter may help you here: [image: format painter icon]

You could also update `Normal Text` to match the formatting of those lines of text, but this would also change other `Normal Text` in the document.